# Salesforce marketing cloud journey builder's decision split equals today not working properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

thank you for your time helping with this thread.

**Summary:** I am making journey builder based on Salesforce data when a person account is updated. There are "first funded date" and "last funded date" with date/time about their funding as in the screenshot. Depending on these fields' values, different emails will be sent.

**Problem:** Comparing last funded date with **contact data** to "today" using decision split always return "False". I tried to diagnose myself what's wrong but couldn't. Checking data on Salesforce CRM, the audience result should be distributed in different branches of the journey.

Looking forward to hearing your thought, thank you very much

[image: Journey builder screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that when you compare the decision split, it returns false. Assuming your contact data is based on your Sync DEs. I can see that you have a wait period of 20 minutes.

Increase the waiting period from 20 minutes to 45 minutes, if it does not impact the business use case. Sometimes, there could be a delay in the sync and your data is not up to date in the Syc DE and hence it is evaluating to false. For debugging purposes, you could update the contact key and the "first funded date" and "last funded date" in a DE and check what's coming in there.

Comment: Did you double-check your decision split and what attribute you're splitting on? You're splitting on contact data, yes?

Comment: Hi @chorlesbarkley7, correct I'm splitting based on contact data. I tried to increase the waiting period from 20 minutes to 45 minutes as @Swati Mishra recommended but it still failed.

As a result, I tried to come up with an altenative solution for this which involves an automations from SQL activities as journey entry. From there, I used
`cast(account.[First_Funded_Date__c] As Date) = cast(DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) As Date)` as condition and the journey worked fine.